# Projective modules over a semi-local ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, projective-module

I need a little bit of help, I found that theorem, but the book doesn't prove it and gives a reference to another book that I don't have; does anyone have an idea?

> Let $R$ be a semi-local ring, and $M$ a finite projective $R$-module. Show that $M$ is free if the localizations $M_m$ have the same rank for all maximal ideals $m$ of $R$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [**Lemma 1.4.4**](http://books.google.ro/books?id=LF6CbQk9uScC&pg=PA20&lpg=PA20&dq=%22Lemma+1.4.4%22+projective&source=bl&ots=Xl-cAO4PW5&sig=lnl8gKf6DBv4-ZEIxwcQ1uGD3QU&hl=ro&sa=X&ei=OjUiU4PHN8mMtAbBoYDwCA&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22Lemma%201.4.4%22%20projective&f=true) in Bruns and Herzog, *Cohen-Macaulay Rings*.